# JSF not rendering correctly

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a project where I have to make a JSF page, Servlet and couple of Beans and deploy it to the Tomcat.

When I create a JSF application in IntelliJ Idea everything works perfectly (well, except for adding Apche Commons libs, but that is a known issue).

But when I try to add all the libraries needed to the existing (originally non-jsf) project, it renders incorrectly:

[image: Image One]

As you can see, there are still `<h:...>` tags and two body tags. When rendering the same page in originally non-jsf project I get this:

[image: Image Two]

The code of the page is following (nevermind it's weirdness, it's completely devoted to testing the output):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="main.css"/>
    <title>Synchronization</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="start" action="synch" method="post">
        <h:button h:form="start">Start</h:button>


        <p:commandButton styleClass="buttonLeft" value="Синхронизация"
                         action="synchronization?faces-redirect=true"
                         immediate="true"/>
    </h:form>

    <p:editor value="lol?" />


</h:body>
</html>
```

The only difference is that in originally non-jsf project filename is `index.jsp`, and in jsf project it's `index.xhtml`.

Any help?

Comment: Did you map the JSF servlet to server *.xhtml pages?

Comment: Now I did and everything works, thanks